# Where to save "state" (an date for example) in a BizTalk solution?

Tags: biztalk

I need to save a date of "last run", use it in an orchestration and update it for every run. An alternative is to use a singleton Orchestration, but it will loose it's variable value if someone terminates it. I tried using Get and Set CommonId, as Brian did here: [Creating an incrementing, persisted daily sequence number for a BizTalk Map](http://www.brianloesgen.com/blog/2007/12/6/creating-an-incrementing-persisted-daily-sequence-number-for.html), but didn't understand how. I am under the impression then SetCommonId only creates an relation with an AppId. An other alternative is to use a custom database, but if there is a solution out-of-the-box I rather use that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no out of the box functionality for this.  The best solution would be to persist it to a DB.

Comment: This is exactly what we do and is a simple and elegant way to do it. 
Extra Tip: You shouldn't modify any out of the box BizTalk databases (you'll likely invalidate support from MS) so make sure to create your own database to store things like this.

Comment: Thx for your answers, I will go with the database solution :)